# App rejected for not performing as advertised (background locations)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I got rejected by the apple review team. The reason was:

> 2.3 - Apps that do not perform as advertised by the developer will be rejected
>
> We were unable to locate some of the features described in your marketing >materials or release notes. Specifically, your app informs the user to allow >background location, however, there is no setting within your app.

If I go to the device settings and find my apps settings, I see the following:
[image: Screenshot from device settings]

I've got the following background modes in my plist file:
[image: Background modes in plist file]

Apple sends me this screenshot along with the review:
[image: Apple screenshot from review]

Also if someone could be helpful with telling me the best way to get in touch with Apple. I've tried writing comments to the rejection in the Resolution Center, but I don't hear back.

Comment: Is I understand, Apple says that you are tracking the users location in the background but the app does noting whit this data. Sorry to say that the only way to contact the review board is by responding to the rejection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot tell you why Apple may have rejected your app; we can only guess (at best).

Apple's testers do not always see the same things that you see, as you've submitted an app for production, whereas you're testing it in a development environment. This is why it's important to do Ad-Hoc and/or [TestFlight beta testing](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/7.0.0.13.7.2.7.9.3.1.2.3.3.1.1.13.1).

You have to be sure that your app (and all of its functionality) works not only for you in a development environment, but also for others in a sample production environment (ideally on a wide range of devices).

The only way to know what the testers saw is to ask for clarification from them via the Resolution Center, which you say you have already done. The best thing to do is to wait, but if you don't get a response in a reasonable amount of time (say, a week or two), you may want to [contact the team](https://developer.apple.com/contact/app-store/).

If you truly believe that this rejection was in error, you can [appeal it](https://developer.apple.com/contact/app-store/?topic=appeal).

Comment: I downloaded the app through test-flight on the same dev device and sure enough, the location setting was gone in device settings... Any ideas why that can be?

Comment: @JensFrandsen I don't know; you may have to do something with permissions or provisioning profiles in Member Center. I would Google it and see if you can find anything; if not, ask another question and see what others have to say.

Comment: I found the cause now. The app was testing for location authorization before actually requesting it for the first time. I removed the check and then iOS asked the user the authorize location services the first time it was used by the app. This added the location setting to the device settings. The reason I didn't see the problem was that the iOS was remembering autorisation across installs. I'm pretty sure I have uninstalled it several times without seeing this issue.

Comment: @JensFrandsen That's interesting; something like along those lines has happened to me with push notifications and authorization a couple of times.

Comment: Uninstalling the app does not immediately delete user-granted permissions, such as location and push. I think it takes about 24 hours for those to be removed AFTER the app is removed. I suspect this is to allow the user to reinstall the app without having to reauthorize the special permissions. But, yes, it makes testing a pain.

Comment: you can also reset privacy settings on the iphone. This doesn't require you to uninstall the app